# Moving from legacy function global-set-key to keymap-global-set

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, help

The documentation in the release of GNU Emacs 29.0.50  states that `global-set-key` is a legacy function; instructing people that the recommended function to use is `keymap-global-set`.

What would be the replacement to

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") (kbd "C-x C-;"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "C-;" "C-x C-;")
```

---

**Caveat:** I know nothing about `keymap-global-set`. I just tried that in an Emacs 29 pretest build, and it seems to set `C-;` to the command that's bound to `C-x C-;`.

The doc string of `keymap-global-set` doesn't say clearly that argument `COMMAND` can be a key description (what `kbd` returns) of a key sequence bound to some command. Maybe it should?

In fact, I think `COMMAND` is not clear in the doc of `keymap-global-set` and its siblings. Clearly it's not the same as the `COMMAND` arg of `global-set-key`, `define-key`, etc. For those functions, a sexp such as `(kbd "C-x C-;")` is what's meant, and not a string such as `"C-x C-;"`.  The latter doesn't work for those "legacy" binding functions -- `kbd` is needed, to distinguish the arg as a "command"/"binding".

What's a "command", as argument to the "legacy" binding functions and their purported replacements?

A sexp such as `(kbd "C-x C-;")` can be used with **`command-execute`**: `(command-execute (kbd "C-x C-;"))`.  A string such as `(kbd "C-x C-;")` cannot.  And the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html) makes clear that **command** means this:

> **“command”**
>
> An object which **can be invoked via the `command-execute`**
> primitive, usually due to the user typing in a key sequence
> “bound” to that
> command.  *Note Interactive Call::.  A command is usually a
> function; if the function is written in Lisp, it is made into a
> command by an ‘interactive’ form in the function definition (*note
> Defining Commands::).  Commands that are functions can also be
> called from Lisp expressions, just like other functions.

(On the other hand, function `commandp` returns `t` for *any* string, interpreting it as a keyboard macro.   That's *not* what's involved for argument `COMMAND` in "legacy" binding functions such as `define-key`.)

It seems clear that in "legacy" key bindings, argument `COMMAND` or `BINDING` is a command in the sense of *"An object which can be invoked via the `command-execute` primitive"*.

Apparently that's not what such an argument means for the new-fangled replacement functions - you can't use `"C-x C-;"` with `command-execute`.  And I find nowhere any description of what those functions require as their `COMMAND` argument.

---

FWIW, it seems to me that those who introduced `keymap-set` etc. (and even expect those new functions, which essentially just add the syntax sugar of letting/making you *not* use `kbd`, to replace the longstanding and newly baptized as "legacy" functions) did a not-quite-fully-baked job of adding their doc and updating the existing doc. I could be wrong, but (so far) it looks that way to me. On the other hand, I have only a pretest version of Emacs 29, and 29 is not yet released. I'm hoping the doc will be clear when it's released.

Comment: Yes, converting my configuration from the newly legacy `define-key`&co to `keymap-set`, etc. turned into quite a project. It is not just removal of `kbd`, the allowed syntax in the definition of keys is different. E.g. things like `\C`, `[tab]`, `[remap]` no longer work and need to be updated.

Comment: FWIW, there's no obligation to convert to using the `keymap-*` functions.