# How can I bind Option+up-arrow to scrolling command?

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I'm on a Mac, using iTerm2. 'Option' is the same as Alt, and Alt is Meta in emacs.

First, in emacs I typed `C-h k` followed by `Option-Up` (Hold option key and press up arrow). The output was

```
ESC <up> (translated from ESC M-[ A) is undefined
```

So I added this to my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<ESC-up>")  'scroll-down-command)
```

I've also tried

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>")  'scroll-down-command)
```

(Note, `scroll-down-command` does what I would call scrolling **up**, and vice versa.)

After reloading .emacs, pressing Option-up gives the following error:

```
ESC <up> is undefined
```

Thanks - I'd appreciate any help with this.

**Update 1:**

I was able to set this interactively using the following:

1. `M-x global-set-key`
2. Press Option + Up-arrow
3. Enter `scroll-down-command`

Which worked. Typing `C-h k` followed by Option + Up-arrow produced the message:

```
ESC <up> (translated from ESC M-[ A) runs the command scroll-down-command
```

I'm still not clear how this differs from what I added to .emacs.

**Update 2:**

I'm using GNU Emacs 29.1. According to [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/77864/2147), `global-set-key` is now a legacy function in v29, and the recommended function to use instead is `keymap-global-set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pre-Emacs-29:**

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <up>") 'scroll-down-command)
```

**Emacs-29:**

Use keymap-global-set instead:

```
(keymap-global-set "ESC <up>"   'scroll-down-command)
(keymap-global-set "ESC <down>" 'scroll-up-command)
```

Note: `keymap-global-set` is new as of emacs 29.0, and `global-set-key` is now a legacy function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different syntax for the key:

```
(global-set-key [M-up] 'scroll-down-command)
```

Comment: I still get the same error message: ESC <up> is undefined.