# Changing key binding definitions

Tags: key-bindings

I read somewhere that emacs v29.1 has changed the way that you can define key bindings...

ie previously you would write:-

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'save-buffer)
```

now you can write:-

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "C-c y" 'clipboard-yank)
```

Is there a simple way to convert one to the other? Possibly a sed script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving from legacy function global-set-key to keymap-global-set](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77864/moving-from-legacy-function-global-set-key-to-keymap-global-set)

Comment: If you mean a non-interactive way then the question has nothing really to do with either of the functions you cite. It's instead about transforming Lisp code across a set of files. And that too is likely a duplicate question.

Comment: I looked  at the post mentioned, but the solution seemed too complicated. As an alternative I've come up with my own sed script. 
~sed -e 's/global-set-key (kbd/keymap-global-set/' -e 's/)//'~

Answer (score 3):

Don’t bother. `global-set-key` isn’t going away, and `keymap-global-set` doesn’t do anything new. Changing your config in this way won’t actually accomplish anything.